# Default unit for font-size?

Tags: css

Various texts on the net claim that "pt" is the default font-size unit when none is provided, however, my own testing seems to demonstrate otherwise. I have read many documents on W3C covering font-size for CSS 1-3, and I can't seem to locate an actual reference to a default unit in any of the specifications.

I have tested this in both Chrome and IE9 and get the exact same results with each: the element lacking a unit is the smallest, the px element is in the middle, and the pt element is the largest. I attempted to match the size using many other units defined by the W3C (such as "mm", "ex", "pc", etc.) but *none* of the test elements match up in size to the targeted element (the one lacking units).

Any insight would be appreciated.

```
<div style="font-size: 20;">20 size</div>
<div style="font-size: 20px;">20px size</div>
<div style="font-size: 20pt;">20pt size</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the ["CSS Fonts Module Level 3"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#font-size-prop) the `font-size` property can have values that are:

> Value: <absolute-size> | <relative-size> | <length> | <percentage>

[`<absolute-size>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#absolute-size-value), [`<relative-size>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#relative-size-value), and [`<percentage>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#percentage-size-value) are defined in the same spec, and are all either keywords (e.x. `small`, `larger`, etc) or have percentage units.

`<length>` being more generic is defined in ["CSS Values and Units Module Level 3"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#lengths):

> Lengths refer to distance measurements and are denoted by <length> in the property definitions. A length is a [dimension](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#dimension). However, for zero lengths the unit identifier is optional (i.e. can be syntactically represented as the <number> 0).

What this means is that unitless numbers for `font-size` are invalid, with an explicit exception for `0`.

---

With that said, what size is `<div style="font-size: 20;">20 size</div>` being rendered at?

The rendered `font-size` of an element will depend on **a lot of things**. However, if we're able to assume that

- the user hasn't customized their default `font-size`
- the browser is using default styles
- there are no parent elements that would otherwise change the `font-size` (e.x. `<font>`, `<sub>`, `<h1>`...yes it would be invalid markup to have those elements as parents, but it would still change the `font-size`)

Then the default `font-size` in every modern browser that I'm aware of currently is `16px`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for it being ignored? Not that I doubt you, I'm just curious how/why I seemed to have missed this in the spec (if that's even where it is).

Comment: I do believe you're correct, I just tested and it is precisely 16px (which I recall seeing listed somewhere as the default text size for some browsers).

Comment: I'll start by linking to the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), and I'll update if I find the relevant subsections about the handling of invalid css rules.

Comment: [font-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props) requires a [length](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length) (and other formats, feel free to read through them) where it states: "The format of a length value is a <number> immediately followed by a unit identifier. After a zero length, the unit identifier is optional." Also, it's good of you to call me out on that, as it keeps me on my toes.

Comment: Interesting, that's pretty much what I discovered, too. Thanks!

Comment: I am sure you then have come across the fundamental difference between pt, mm etc, that are "physical" measurements, based on paper print, while as px relate to pixels, obviously, and em to the design of the actual fontface. As some fonts looks bigger though they have the same x-height, might also confuse.

Comment: @zzzzBov sorry meant to do a simple clean up and got a little edit happy.  No problems if you wish to prune it a bit.  thx.

Comment: @Benteh I don't think em has anything to do with the font face, but please see edits describing it and let me know if I'm missing anything.  thx.

Comment: @Lee thank you for bringing my attention to this seriously out-of-date post of mine. I have decided to do a complete rewrite. In the future I would encourage you to post your own answer rather than making such large edits. Specifically in this case: if you think your updates have information you'd like to keep, I would encourage you to post them as an answer.