# Font Resize is not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size

My page header bar has a + and - to use to increase and decrease the font (using the function below)...

This all works correctly.  I'm storing the new font size value in a cookie.

The desired outcome is if you a) refresh the page, or b) go to a different page on the site, it sets the font size to what was stored... however, this is not the case.

Here is my code bits... (using a script.js file)

```
var resize = new Array('.resizable');
$(document).ready(function() {
    resize = resize.join(',');

    var resetFont = $(resize).css('font-size');

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $(resize).css('font-size', resetFont);
        setFontSizeCookieValue(resetFont);
    });

    //increases font size when "+" is clicked
    $(".increase").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();  
        changeFontSize(true);
        return false;
    });

    //decrease font size when "-" is clicked
    $(".decrease").click(function(){
        changeFontSize(false);
        return false;
    });

    // set the page font size based on cookie
    setPageInitialFontSize();
});

function setPageInitialFontSize() {
    var currentSize = $(resize).css('font-size');
    if (currentSize !== getFontSize()) changeFontSize();
};

// font size changer
function changeFontSize(increase) {
    var currentFontSize = getFontSize();    //getFontSize gets the cookie value or, if not set, returns 16
    var currentFontValue = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSize;
    if (increase !== undefined) newFontSize = Math.floor((increase) ? currentFontValue * 1.2 : currentFontValue * 0.8);
    $(resize).css('font-size', newFontSize);
    setFontSizeCookieValue(newFontSize);
};
```

I'm not showing the 'cookie' code calls (set and get) as they are working properly setting/getting the cookie values.

When you click the + or - buttons, they call the changeFontSize function with the correct parameter value.  When the page loads/refreshes, setPageInitialFontSize() is being called...

Stepping through setPageInitialFontSize, it tests the current size (16px) with the getFontSize call (19) and flows through changeFontSize, which does everything its supposed to do, but it's like 
`$(resize).css('font-size', newFontSize);`
doesn't actually do anything here...

So I could use any help trying to figure out why this isn't working...

Comment: You are ignoring units in `currentFontValue` and `newFontSize`, which is invalid for the `font-size` property, so it will use whatever the default font size is for your browser/OS/setting, which is usually 16px. See [Default unit for font-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7907749/215552)

Comment: Yeah, but a) it still works fine for the increase and decrease buttons (which do the same thing) and b) I was still having the issue when the line was ```$(resize).css('font-size', newFontSize + "px");```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are trying to achieve , use this code or follow along with your code just see what you are missing as i cant see cookies part in your code, check here the working code
https://jsbin.com/wofogejiye/edit?html,js,console,output

```
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
       <title>Increase and Decrease Font Using Jquery and CSS</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><
        /script>   

          <script type="text/javascript">

      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <input type="button" class="increase" value=" + ">
      <input type="button" class="decrease" value=" - "/>
      <input type="button" class="resetMe" value=" = ">
      <div>Click Respected Buttons to Increase or Decrease the Font </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){   

          var originalSize = getFontSizeLocalStorage()        
          // reset    
          $('div').css('font-size', originalSize);         
          $(".resetMe").click(function(){           
          $('div').css('font-size', originalSize);         
          });
        $('div').css('font-size'); 
          // Increase Font Size          
          $(".increase").click(function(){         
          var currentSize = getFontSizeLocalStorage()         
          var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.2;          
          $('div').css('font-size', currentSize);
            addToLocalStorage(currentSize)
          return false;          
          });        

          // Decrease Font Size       
          $(".decrease").click(function(){        

          var currentSize =getFontSizeLocalStorage()       
          var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*0.8;        
          $('div').css('font-size', currentSize);   
              addToLocalStorage(currentSize)
          return false;         
          });         
        });

        function addToLocalStorage(fontSize){
        window.localStorage.setItem("fontSize",fontSize)
        }
        function getFontSizeLocalStorage(){
        if( window.localStorage.getItem("fontSize")){
        return window.localStorage.getItem("fontSize")
        }
        return $('div').css('font-size')
        }

</script>
```