# Meaning of font-size on SVG

Tags: svg, font-size

I have the following SVG file:

```
<svg height="1000.0" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 5.0 5.0" width="1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g>
      <g fill="none" stroke="none" />
      <g stroke-width="0.005" stroke="black">
         <g fill="black" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="0.05" stroke="none" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0.0125 -0.025)">
            <text x="4.50" y="5.00">101°</text>
         </g>
         <line x1="0.00" x2="5.00" y1="5.00" y2="5.00" />
      </g>
      <g stroke-width="0.005" stroke="black">
         <g fill="black" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="0.05" stroke="none" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0.025 0.00625)">
            <text x="-0.00" y="0.05">11°</text>
         </g>
         <line x1="0.00" x2="0.00" y1="5.00" y2="0.00" />
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

The font size is 0.05, which is very small. The `font-size` attribute in svg refer to the `font-size` property CSS specification. There is no unit, so I looked in the following [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907749/default-unit-for-font-size). If I change the size from 0.05 to 0.0.5px, I have the same result, so I assume that the browser (in my case Edge or Firefox, or Chrome all have have the same result) consider no unit as pixel units.

It seems that the size of the font depend on the viewbox, because with the current svg file, I have the following result:
[image: Image with font size]
Now if I remove the viewbox, with this svg specification:

```
<svg height="1000.0" version="1.1" width="1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <g>
      <g fill="none" stroke="none" />
      <g stroke-width="0.005" stroke="black">
         <g fill="black" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="0.05" stroke="none" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0.0125 -0.025)">
            <text x="4.50" y="5.00">101°</text>
         </g>
         <line x1="0.00" x2="5.00" y1="5.00" y2="5.00" />
      </g>
      <g stroke-width="0.005" stroke="black">
         <g fill="black" font-family="Arial, sans-serif" font-size="0.05px" stroke="none" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(0.025 0.00625)">
            <text x="-0.00" y="0.05">11°</text>
         </g>
         <line x1="0.00" x2="0.00" y1="5.00" y2="0.00" />
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

I have the following result (so not visible font because too small):
[image]
What's the algorithm to use with a (for example pixel-unit) `font-size` in SVG, relative to the viewbox?

Comment: So what your are saying if that if there is no viewbox its in pixels. But when it's a viewbox how it's working? It's a percentage of the total viewbox size? (so in this case 0.05 x viewbox size?)

Comment: Per https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#FontSizeProperty % of viewBox height.

Comment: @RobertLongson sorry but this is plain wrong. Only if a `%` unit was present the size would be relative. The presence of a viewBox does not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers without units or with px units are called **userspace coordinates/sizes**. They are local to the coordinate system in use where the element is placed. A `viewBox` of `0 0 5 5` describes a drawing region that is 5 units both in width and height. A text that is a child element and has `font-size: 0.05` is 1/100 of the `viewBox` height.

The userspace coordinate system has no units and is abstract in the sense that it has to be fitted in some space (the "viewport") before it is rendered. You can use units in the userspace context, but they need to be converted into unitless userspace numbers. (For px, trivially just delete the unit.)

Only afterwards, when you know the size of the viewport and how to fit the drawing region inside, you can compute real-world pixel (for a screen), or point (for printing), or centimeter (for a plotter) values.

If the `<svg>` element has a `width` and `height` of 1000px, the drawing region defined by the `viewBox` is rendered by multiplying the userspace units with a factor of 200px, so that it fills the element. In other words: what in  terms of the coordinate system *inside* the `viewBox` is a length of 1, is 200px in regard to the *rendered* `<svg>` element. A text with a font size of 0.05 is rendered accordingly at a size of 0.05 * 200px = 10px.

If there is no `viewBox` attribute present, the factor is simply 1px. A userspace unit of 1 is rendered at 1px, a font size of 0.05 is rendered as 0.05px.